# "Human settlement of" or "human settlement in"?

Tags: prepositions

I came across a sentence which was:

If unchecked, intensive human settlement of coastal zones across the globe will lead to further deterioration in the quality of marine environment.

What difference would it have made if "in" was used after settlement instead of "of"? Because I think that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=settlement%20in%2Csettlement%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csettlement%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csettlement%20of%3B%2Cc0) might be a little revealing here...

[image]

Clearly, both are attested. A look at the specific Google books results shows that both are used in this sort of situation, as well as each being used in some others. Some others, such as referring to a specific settlement by name, are attested with both. Playing with the different English corpora produces very similar results.

So, both are arguably acceptable, it doesn't depend on American vs British, fact or fiction, and numerically "settlement of" is more common, though they are closer than they once were.

Personally, for using ***settlement*** as an action noun, as it is here, only ***settlement of*** feels right to me, but that may be personal bias. For ***settlement*** as a 'normal' noun, referring to a place people are settled, ***settlement of*** should be followed by the settlement name, and ***settlement in*** should be followed by an indication of the location. *That* I'm confident of, though I couldn't say why.

Answer (score 0):

I personally see the difference as:

Human settlement of coastal zones - implies the whole coastal zone is settled, or that there's no space beyond the scope of settling.

Human settlement in coastal zones - they may have large settlements in the zones, but they don't occupy the whole zone.